# How can I inject css class in Vuejs component with javascript?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Sorry for my question. I actually want to inject new css class and its hover attributes which I got from a web service. I'm trying to put it into #style#
 #/style# tags.

Comment: do you read this and try to use: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html ?

Comment: Sorry for my question. I actually want to inject new css class and its hover attributes which I got from a web service. I'm trying to put it into <style></style> tags.

Answer (score 3):

The [official docs for Class and Style Bindings/Binding HTML Classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) show several ways. Below are the most common and some useful demos.

> ### Object Syntax
>
> We can pass an object to `v-bind:class` to dynamically toggle classes:
>
> ```
> <div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
> ```

> The above syntax means the presence of the active class will be
> determined by the truthiness of the data property `isActive`.

See demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    isActive: true
  }
})
```

```css
.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">My DIV</div>
  <button @click="isActive = !isActive">activate/deactivate</button>
</div>
```

> #### Multiple classes
>
> You can have multiple classes toggled by having more fields in the
> object. In addition, the v-bind:class directive can also co-exist with
> the plain class attribute. So given the following template:
>
> ```
> <div class="static"
>      v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }">
> </div>
> ```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    isActive: true,
    hasError: false
  }
})
```

```css
.active { background: yellow }
.text-danger { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }">My DIV</div>
  <button @click="isActive = !isActive">toggle isActive</button>
  <button @click="hasError= !hasError">toggle hasError</button>
</div>
```

> ### Array Syntax
>
> We can pass an array to `v-bind:class` to apply a list of classes:
>
> ```html
> <div v-bind:class="[activeClass, errorClass]"></div>
> ```
>
> ```js
> data: {
>   activeClass: 'active',
>   errorClass: 'text-danger'
> }
> ```

And, of course, you can change that data and the HTML will react. Another demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    activeClass: 'active',
    errorClass: 'text-danger'
  }
})
```

```css
.active { background: green }
.inactive { background: yellow }
.text-danger { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <div v-bind:class="[activeClass, errorClass]">My DIV</div>
  <button @click="activeClass = 'inactive'">activeClass to inactive</button>
  <button @click="activeClass = 'active'">activeClass to active</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for my question. I actually want to inject new css class and its hover attributes which I got from a web service. I'm trying to put it into <style></style> tags.